# Attempting to add snow to a page but it completely wipes out my HTML and nothing displays

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a snowfall background which I got from a css tricks website. The snow looks cool but for some reason the background hides my html content. Please see code below.
How can I keep this cool background as EXACTLY THAT, a background so that it does not take over the entire page
? I just need the code to run behind the scene while the html can do its job.
I appreciate any help I can get and I know my code is not perfect. Also, I am just learning and again any help I can get is great.

HTML:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canv'),
$ = c.getContext("2d");
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
h = c.height = window.innerHeight;

Snowy();

function Snowy() {
  var snow, arr = [];
  var num = 600, tsc = 1, sp = 1;
  var sc = 1.3, t = 0, mv = 20, min = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    snow = new Flake();
    snow.y = Math.random() * (h + 50);
    snow.x = Math.random() * w;
    snow.t = Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2);
    snow.sz = (100 / (10 + (Math.random() * 100))) * sc;
    snow.sp = (Math.pow(snow.sz * .8, 2) * .15) * sp;
    snow.sp = snow.sp < min ? min : snow.sp;
    arr.push(snow);
  }


  go();
  function go(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(go);
    $.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    $.fillStyle = 'hsla(242, 95%, 3%, 1)';
    $.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    $.fill();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      f = arr[i];
      f.t += .05;
      f.t = f.t >= Math.PI * 2 ? 0 : f.t;
      f.y += f.sp;
      f.x += Math.sin(f.t * tsc) * (f.sz * .3);
      if (f.y > h + 50) f.y = -10 - Math.random() * mv;
      if (f.x > w + mv) f.x = - mv;
      if (f.x < - mv) f.x = w + mv;
      f.draw();}


  }



  function Flake() {
    this.draw = function() {
      this.g = $.createRadialGradient(this.x, this.y, 0, this.x, this.y, this.sz);
      this.g.addColorStop(0, 'hsla(255,255%,255%,1)');
      this.g.addColorStop(1, 'hsla(255,255%,255%,0)');
      $.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      $.fillStyle = this.g;
      $.beginPath();
      $.arc(this.x, this.y, this.sz, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      $.fill();}
  }

}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  c.width = w = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = h = window.innerHeight;
}, false);
```

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Molle:400italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);
    body{
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Molle', cursive;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <canvas id='canv'></canvas>
    <body>
    <div id="home">    

                       

    <div id="wrapper">
    <header> 
   

     <h1>My Site</h1>
    <div class="snow"></div>
    <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
 <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
 <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
      </div>
       </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canv'), 
$ = c.getContext("2d");
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth, 
h = c.height = window.innerHeight;

Snowy();

function Snowy() {
  var snow, arr = [];
  var num = 600, tsc = 1, sp = 1;
  var sc = 1.3, t = 0, mv = 20, min = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      snow = new Flake();
      snow.y = Math.random() * (h + 50);
      snow.x = Math.random() * w;
      snow.t = Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2);
  snow.sz = (100 / (10 + (Math.random() * 100))) * sc;
  snow.sp = (Math.pow(snow.sz * .8, 2) * .15) * sp;
  snow.sp = snow.sp < min ? min : snow.sp;
  arr.push(snow);
}


 go();
  function go(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(go);
      $.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      $.fillStyle = 'hsla(242, 95%, 3%, 1)';
      $.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      $.fill();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      f = arr[i];
      f.t += .05;
      f.t = f.t >= Math.PI * 2 ? 0 : f.t;
      f.y += f.sp;
      f.x += Math.sin(f.t * tsc) * (f.sz * .3);
      if (f.y > h + 50) f.y = -10 - Math.random() * mv;
      if (f.x > w + mv) f.x = - mv;
      if (f.x < - mv) f.x = w + mv;
      f.draw();}


}



function Flake() {
   this.draw = function() {
      this.g = $.createRadialGradient(this.x, this.y, 0, this.x, this.y, this.sz);
      this.g.addColorStop(0, 'hsla(255,255%,255%,1)');
      this.g.addColorStop(1, 'hsla(255,255%,255%,0)');
      $.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      $.fillStyle = this.g;
      $.beginPath();
      $.arc(this.x, this.y, this.sz, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      $.fill();}
  }

}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  c.width = w = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = h = window.innerHeight;
}, false);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Molle:400italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);
body{
background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
margin: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: 'Molle', cursive;
z-index:10;
}
#canv{
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index:-1;
}
h1{
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My Site</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id='canv'></canvas>
<div id="home">    



<div id="wrapper">
<header>    


 <h1>My Site</h1>
<div class="snow"></div>
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: just used simple css to the canvas

Comment: I get the black background and nav list with your code but not the snowfall. Any ideas?

Comment: so i tried your code all on one html page and it worked. For some reason when I separate the css and js code to external sheets, the background remains black and the snow no longer works. Any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: when you put external css, and call javascript function like that, the function will add and apply css color as internal css. it may cause the problem which you are having

Comment: why is that? Also my h1 appears in the background and even if I use css to change the color of my h1 is remains black in the background.

Comment: check above output

Comment: just put canvas css as internal css

Comment: and rest of the css as external css

Comment: @Thank you for all of your help Nihal.

Comment: glad to help you